# Why doesn't \date work?

Tags: date

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, 12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsaddr, amssymb, graphicx, dsfont,}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\raggedbottom

 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
 \newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
  \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
  \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
 \newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

  \usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{
body={6.5in, 9.0in},
left=1.25in,
right=1.25in,
top=1.25in,
bottom=1.25in
 }
\usepackage[
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=Blue,
citecolor=Brown]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{footmisc}
%\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.4cm} %footnote spacing

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ima}{Im}
 \newcommand{\namedthm}[2]{\theoremstyle{plain}
 \newtheorem*{thm#1}{Theorem #1}\begin{thm#1}#2\end{thm#1}}

 \usepackage{float}

 \begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\thispagestyle{empty}

 \begin{center}
{\Large Title}
\end{center}\vskip 1cm 

\begin{center}
\date{October 18, 2022}
\end{center}\vskip 2cm 



 \end{document}
```

I do not want to show the author and want to show a date that is not today. But \date does not work (\today works, though). How can I fix it?

Comment: Using `\date` only makes sense if you also use `\maketitle`. It doesn't look like you're using `\maketitle`, though, does it?

Comment: `\date` sets the date, which `\maketitle` shows.  What are you wanting to happen?  Why not just have `October 18, 2022` in the first place?